# How to compute the log likelihood of a Poisson Hidden Markov Model once I know all the parameters

Tags: poisson-distribution, bayesian-network

I know that the answer is maybe pretty straightforward, but the Expectation Maximization algorithm confused me a little.

So basically my problem is this:

I have a set of data and applied the Expectation Maximization algorithm to find the transition probability and the lambdas of my Poisson Hidden Markov Model, now how do I compute the log-likelihood?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean the log-likelihood of the data assuming your inferred transition probabilities and hidden state space and given data? Also, did you assume your hidden space (space of Poisson parameters) was discrete? If discrete, then you can marginalize over the unknown (discrete) hidden states, otherwise likely you have to use the inferred continuous hidden states you found from EMA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented EM algorithm. Surely you will have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values from forward backward algorithms. 
Here, $\alpha_t(j) = P(x_t=j,Z_{\{1:t\}}\vert \theta)$.

$Z_{\{1:t\}}$ is all the emissions (observations) up to time $t$.

$\theta$ are the learned parameters from EM.

Now the log likelihood is log($P(Z_{\{1:t\}}\vert \theta)) = log(\sum_{j} \alpha_t(j))$